# Can I un-assign (clear) all fields of an instance?

Tags: java, oop, field

Is there a simple way to clear all fields of an instance from a an instance? I mean, I would like to remove all values assigned to the fields of an instance.

**ADDED**

From the main thread I start a window and another thread which controls state of the window (the last thread, for example, display certain panels for a certain period of time). I have a class which contains state of the window (on which stage the user is, which buttons he already clicked).

In the end, user may want to start the whole process from the beginning (it is a game). So, I decided. So, if everything is executed from the beginning, I would like to have all parameter to be clean (fresh, unassigned).

**ADDED**

The main thread, creates the new object which is executed in a new thread (and the old thread is finished). So, I cannot create a new object from the old thread. I just have a loop in the second thread.

Comment: Can you give an example of when you would want to do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply create a new object of the class that holds the state and use that? Much simpler, less code to maintain and no risk of getting the clearing code wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get it. How can you programmatically decide how to clear various fields?

For normal attributes it can be easy (`var = null`) but what about composite things or collection? Should it be `collection = null`, or `collection.removeAll()`?

This question is looking for synctactic sugar that wouldn't make so much sense..

The best way is to write out your own `reset()` method to customize the behaviour for every single object.. maybe you can *patternize* it using an

```
interface Resettable
{
  void reset()
}
```

but nothing more than that..

Answer (score 4):

> *Is there a simple way to clear all fields of an instance from a an instance? I mean, I would like to remove all values assigned to the fields of an instance.*

Yes, just assign a default value to each one of them. It would take you about 20-30 mins. and will run well forever<sup>*( YMMV)</sup>

Create a method: `reset` and invoke it

```
class YourClass {
    int a;
    int b;
    boolean c;
    double d;
    String f;
    // and so on... 
    public void method1(){}
    public void method2(){}
    public void method3(){}
    // etc. 
    // Magic method, reset all the attributes of your instance...
    public void reset(){
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        c = false;
        d = 0.0;
        f = "";
     }
}
```

And then just invoke it in your code:

```
   .... 
   YourClass object = new YourClass();
   Thread thread = YourSpecificNewThread( object );
   thread.start();

   ... // Later on you decide you have to reset the object just call your method:

   object.reset(); // like new
```

I don't really see where's the problem with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may use reflection:

Try something like this:

```
Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
  f.setAccessible(true);
  f.set(object, null);
}
```

It's not a beautifull solution, but may work for you.

Comment: Whenever it field type is boolean, int or float or any other primitive type which does not recognizes "null" it will throw Exception. Tell me should I downvote this answer although I know that you said "It's not a beautiful solution"

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than setting `null` to all of them.

As an aside, i find that a particular weird idea. You would have better re-creating a new instance, instead of trying to reset your old one.

Comment: why do you think it weird? Is recycling of objects a bad idea ??

Comment: @Marcos I can think no case wshere it could be a good idea to void content of an object without garbaging it (in which case it would be better to re-create a new one, no ?). After all, Java provides excellent support for garbage collection, which can only be helped by simple object graphs. And when one plays with references, well, it can't help.

Comment: when you set all references of an object to `null`, the gc would on its own clean up the unreferenced data. This way, during this recycling phase, you clean up your no-longer-useful data & use the same container object for the next purpose. As an example, lets say, you have a `list` of 500 `Integers`, then when you recycle it, all references to the 500 `Integers` are set to null thus the unreferenced data would be deleted by gc and new list would use the same collection object. Am I going wrong somewhere ?

Comment: @Marcos no, you're totally right. However, what I question is the very fact of taking one object, emptying it to reload later another content in. From my experience, it's by far simpler to simply create another object containing the new values.

Comment: What about an object from an object pool?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear a filter (Serializable) that your application "can handle his null" fields, you can use BeanUtils ([Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/)):

```
    Field[] fields = filter.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field f : fields) {
        if (f.getName().endsWith("serialVersionUID")) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(filter, f.getName(), null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            FacesUtils.handleError(LOG, "Erro limpar filtro...", e);
        }
    }
```

I hope it can help you.